# Signal 11 caught. The server exits when the item is delivered via RCON

Tags: linux, ark-survival-evolved

I try to give an object to the player on the server via RCON using the `GiveItemNumToPlayer` command.  After sending the command the object is not issued and the server is shutting down.

The server has no mods. I try to give a simple object (like a pickaxe):

```
2018-07-22 12:52:36: [TheIsland] 2018-07-22 12:52:36: start
2018-07-22 12:52:36: [TheIsland] 2018-07-22 12:52:36: Running /home/ark/ARK/ShooterGame/Binaries/Linux/ShooterGameServer TheIsland?RCONEnabled=True?RCONPort=32330?SessionName=Land?Port=7777?QueryPort=27015?ServerPassword=11111111111?ServerAdminPassword=1111111111?MaxPlayers=5?listen -log -NoBattleEye -server
2018-07-22 12:52:36: [TheIsland] 2018-07-22 12:52:36: Server PID: 7544
2018-07-22 12:52:39: [TheIsland] [S_API FAIL] SteamAPI_Init() failed; SteamAPI_IsSteamRunning() failed.
2018-07-22 12:52:39: [TheIsland] Setting breakpad minidump AppID = 346110
2018-07-22 12:56:24: [TheIsland] 2018-07-22 12:56:24: server is up
2018-07-22 13:03:39: [TheIsland] Signal 11 caught.
2018-07-22 13:03:41: [TheIsland] /usr/local/bin/arkmanager: line 1101:  7544 Segmentation fault      "$arkserverroot/$arkserverexec" "$arkserveropts" "${arkextraopts[@]}"
2018-07-22 13:03:41: [TheIsland] 2018-07-22 13:03:41: Bad PID ''; expected '7544'
2018-07-22 13:03:41: [TheIsland] 2018-07-22 13:03:41: exited with status 0
```